# Openpyxl finds merged cells even though there are none

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm handling excels in my python script and get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_consolidateExcels_v3.py", line 134, in <module>
    colNum = findColOfCell(ws, "xxx", 1)
  File "script_consolidateExcels_v3.py", line 28, in findColOfCell
    if worksheet.cell(row=inRow, column=k).value == val:
AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object has no attribute 'value'
```

The excel file initially had merged cells, but I unmerged everything using Microsoft Excel, yet this error still pops up. I even tried ws.unmerge_cells(), but with no help. (Weirdly enough, at first I wrote and run the script on a windows laptop and this error did not pop up... I sent the script to my mac, and now I get this error... (I can't access the windows laptop currently))

Here is the problematic part:

```
def findColOfCell(worksheet, val, inRow, startCol=1):
    i = 0
    k = startCol
    while i == 0:
        if worksheet.cell(row=inRow, column=k).value == val:
            i = 1
            # here = ord(worksheet.cell(row=inRow, column=k).column)-64 # convert column letter to number
            here = worksheet.cell(row=inRow, column=k).column
        else: k += 1
    return here
```

Comment: Can you just catch the error and pass it? Or it does have some value in the said cell

Comment: You can change the logic to skip `MergedCell`s which you'll need to do anyway: `if getattr(worksheet.cell(…), "value", None == val`

Comment: Well, there may be the value I am looking for...

Comment: So there is no option really to work with merged cells?

Comment: @CharlieClark the problem is the MergedCell has no attribute "value", so this way of skipping the MergedCell doesn't work either.. or I am I missing something out? `if getattr(worksheet.cell(row=in_row, column=k), "value", None == val):
            k += 1`

Comment: `if not hasattr(worksheet.cell(row=in_row, column=k), "value"):` seems to work

Answer (score 1):

If you are merging 3 cells say (1,1) (1,2) and (1,3)

```
sheet.merge_cells(start_row=1, start_column=1, end_row=1, end_column=3)
```

In this case, cell (1,2) and (1,3) will no longer have attribute 'value'.

**You can only assign value to (1,1)** as the cell (1,2) and (1,3) does not exist anymore.

Hope this helps.